# Date with Milliseconds 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS' for in Pyspark data from Hive

Tags: datetime, hive, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, milliseconds

I have a date field stored as a string in HIVE tables, in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS
```

For example:

```
2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754
```

But, we're seeing the following behavior:

- When we select the column in PySpark as `to_timestamp()`, we get `NULL`.
- When we select it as a normal string, it display as `2020-01-20 07:41:....`; it doesn't show the full value.
- When we try to truncate the milliseconds, it shows correctly up to seconds as `2020-01-20 07:41:21`—but we *want* the millisecnds to be included in the PySpark DateFrame to perform transformations.

What is the proper way to query pull a date stored as a string?

Comment: Hi there! I've made a number of edits to your post in order to aid in readability. Please be sure to review them both to make sure everything conveys your intended meaning, but also to learn how to format your posts in the future. Notably, I formatted the date formats as code blocks using backticks (`), and I formatted the bullets as a list by placing each on their own line. While I was at it, I also made some wording changes to help clarify the question, and reiterated the question at the end. Please review, and let me know if everything makes sense.

Comment: @Naresh - did you try out the answer below? did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin, a question on the time format. Why is the milliseconds value - 86754? that would mean 86 seconds and 754 milliseconds? do you mean microseconds? then it makes sense.

Anyway, I tried with the same date format to check if spark can handle it and it does.

Consider a test dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test_df= sqlContext.createDataFrame(["2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754","2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999"],"string").toDF('date')
test_df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------+
|date                     |
+-------------------------+
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754|
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999|
+-------------------------+
test_res = test_df.withColumn("timestamp",F.to_timestamp(F.col('date')))
test_res.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|date                     |timestamp                |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754|
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999|
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

As you can see, there is no error in converting your string as a time stamp. I used this with spark 2.4.0.
Check the dtypes of the result

```
test_res.dtypes
[('date', 'string'), ('timestamp', 'timestamp')]
```

I am still intrigued by your intent. When you have to process your timestamp say by converting it to unix_timestamp, you will get the same value for two rows even if the milliseconds(or microseconds in your case) are different

```
test_res1=test_res.withColumn("unix_time",F.unix_timestamp('date'))
test_res1.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|date                     |timestamp                |unix_time |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86754|1579502481|
|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999|2020-01-20 07:41:21.86999|1579502481|
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

Same is the result when you try to convert your timestamp to int

```
test_longint = test_res1.withColumn("test_int",F.col('timestamp').cast('int'))
test_longint.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|                date|           timestamp| unix_time|  test_int|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
|2020-01-20 07:41:...|2020-01-20 07:41:...|1579502481|1579502481|
|2020-01-20 07:41:...|2020-01-20 07:41:...|1579502481|1579502481|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+
```

Hope this helps. I can explain more if i know more on what you need.